# My own server, 18.04 just one site won't load, locally, all others load, and this one will load on windows laptop

Tags: server

I have got the most weird problem with my server running ubuntu 18.04.

One site won't load on a local mac, or when using the built in firefox on the server itself.  https://goodbyecancer.co.uk however, all the other sites on the server load under all circumstances.

What is even stranger, is that the site in question above, does load, on this network, with a windows laptop. And it loads to the rest of the world.

When I visit the site, is it just me, it states that, it is just me and that the site is up.  If I view the site via a proxy server, it works fine.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: did you mess around with `/etc/hosts` on the server while building the site? What exactly means "doesn't load"?

Comment: Mess around?  I did have to edit the /etc/hosts file to get them to load locally prior to going "live" and then I took all "notes" of the sites down from etc/hosts.

When I mean it won't load.  I mean the site won't show up.  The connection times out.

Comment: That's what I meant, I was assuming that perhaps you forgot to remove something from there.

Comment: It's so weird, 9 sites load, one does not.